# How to test IE6, 7 and 8 compatibility of web page in Win 7 Home edition?

Tags: cross-browser, internet-explorer-6

I am working on a web site development and would like to test the web pages under IE6, 7 and 8 brewers. I am using Win 7 Home edition, and seems that Virtual PC 2007 under this version does not quite support XP mode. Also I need to test some interactions so IT Tester might not be a suitable solution either. Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You can try IE's developer tools (F12) to change Browser mode or try http://spoon.net/browsers (not free though) to emulate the desired browser.